# HTML and CSS table in table without double frame

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to make one, global table, and in the cells I want to put other tables. I don't want to have a double frame and thick lines. When i do this...

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:1px solid black;
}
td, th, tr{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

...I have a double cell. So I added `padding:0px;` in both of them, but then I got a doubled thickness of cell borders. How can I do this to have an effect of one table border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following (basic) markup:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td,
th,
tr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table table {
  border: none;
}
table table tr,
table table td,
table table th {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>inner table 1, cell 1</td>
          <td>inner table 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>inner table 2, cell 1</td>
          <td>inner table 2, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But using yours code I have still double lines (border of global table and border of table table td). I want these borders to coincide but without double thickness effect. When i add table table td { border: none;}, border between cells will disapear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the double borders in the code snippet I've provided. Could you provide a code snippet of what you actually have that we can work from please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-spacing: 0;`

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
}
td,
th,
tr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```